# QGIS defining the nth character where the label could be wrapped

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression, regular-expression

I have the labels, which include a few of the same characters "/". Unfortunately, I cannot simply use the "Wrap on character" option, because it wraps everywhere where this character occurs.

[image]

I am wondering about the option, which would allow me to wrap the text at some nth character instead of each.

Comment: I want to have it wrapped after 4th slash

Comment: You can find some way of inserting some unused char every fourth slash and use that char to wrap by

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using QGIS expressions and @BERA suggestion:

in the label field write the expression:

`regexp_replace ("FieldName", '(.+)(/)(.+)$','\\1:\\3')`

then, use `:` to return the last part of the text

[image]

Comment: this expression will replace the last occurrence of `/`, not necessarily the 4th and not every 4.

Comment: if you can, publish a small dataset

Comment: @JGH the 4th is just an example. At least I should know how to set the breakdown in any nth occurrence other than each.

Comment: @MKR to do it in a timely manner and based on your example:
`regexp_replace( 'VON/FLN/CBF-DUN2/A1/FDN199', '(.+)(/)(.+)(/)(.+)(/)(.+)(/)(.+)','\\1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7:\\9')`:  to replace the 4th `/`

Comment: or using arrays:
`array_to_string(array_slice( string_to_array('VON/FLN/CBF-DUN2/A1/FDN199','/'),0,3),'/')  ||  '\n'  || array_to_string(
array_slice( string_to_array('VON/FLN/CBF-DUN2/A1/FDN199','/'),4,-1),'/')`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using Arrays.

If you want to do it every x times, you can use arrays like this:

```
with_variable('pos',"pos",
array_to_string(array_slice( string_to_array("text",'/'),0,eval(@pos)),'/')  
||'\n'|| -- new line
array_to_string( array_slice( string_to_array("text",'/'),eval(@pos)+1,-1),'/'))
```

the "pos" attribute has a range of 0-3, because arrays start at zero.

[image]

[image]

[image]